# DialogFragment is fullscreen. How to make it small

Tags: android, android-layout

I have this DialogFragment. When I show it, it becomes fullscreen, I mean it overlaps the current screen. How to make it small like an AlertDialog?

I guessed it's because of the RelativeLayout so I wrapped the LinearLayout outside of RelativeLayout but nothing changes.

```
public class LoginDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {

@Override
public void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setStyle(DialogFragment.STYLE_NORMAL, android.R.style.Theme);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(final LayoutInflater inflater, final ViewGroup container,
        final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    final View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.login_dialog, container, false);
    final EditText emailEditText = (EditText)v.findViewById(R.id.emailEditText);
    final EditText passwordEditText = (EditText)v.findViewById(R.id.passwordEditText);
    final Button loginButton = (Button)v.findViewById(R.id.loginButton);
    loginButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(final View v) {
                checkLogin(emailEditText.getText().toString(), passwordEditText.getText().toString());
            }
        });
    return v;
}
}
```

Layout

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/loginTitleTextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="@string/loginDialogTitle"
        android:textColor="@color/White"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/emailEditText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/loginTitleTextView"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/passwordEditText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/emailEditText"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPassword" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/passwordTextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/passwordEditText"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/passwordEditText"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="@string/password"
        android:textColor="@color/White"
        android:textSize="16sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/emailTextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/emailEditText"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/emailEditText"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="@string/email"
        android:textColor="@color/White"
        android:textSize="16sp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/loginButton"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/passwordEditText"
        android:text="@string/loginButtonText" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Have you figured this out by any chance?

Comment: @Emerald214 try this yourFragmentAct  act = new yourfragmentActivity();act.show(); instead of add as fragment .It will show and resize based on the content

Answer (score 2):

Call `setStyle(STYLE_NORMAL, android.R.style.Theme_Dialog);` instead of `setStyle(DialogFragment.STYLE_NORMAL, android.R.style.Theme);` in `onCreate()`. Did it help?

Comment: What's your base theme? Try setStyle(DialogFragment.STYLE_NO_TITLE, android.R.style.Theme_Holo_Light_Dialog); inside the onCreate() method

Comment: I have the same problem and this doesn't change anything at all